# python3 use google app engine to receive email, than how to get date and size properly

Tags: python-3.x, email, google-app-engine

I used GAE-mail to receive email, in the email handle, I am able to received body, sender, subject etc from mail_message.

```
mail_message = mail.InboundEmailMessage(data)
# supported attributes is=>{
         'amp_html',
         'attachments',
         'bcc',
         'body',
         'cc',
         'headers',
         'html',
         'reply_to',
         'sender',
         'subject',
         'to'
        }
```

however, I want some additional attributes, email_size and sentdate, what is the best practice to get these two attributes?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Mail API from Python2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/receiving-mail-with-mail-api) has the field below; it should work for Python3

> date returns the message date.

2. This [sample code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/6f5f3bcb81779679a24e0964a6c57c0c7deabfac/appengine/standard/mail/handle_incoming_email.py) from Google shows length of the message. If you want the size in bytes, you should try `getsizeof` method instead of `len`. See this [example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-get-the-size-of-a-string-in-Python)